# XSIM package and custom grade table

Tags: macros, exercises, exsheets, xsim

How do I go about using the `xsim` package to display a custom gradetable in tags rather than exercises/questions.

So far I have (my MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,tasks,siunitx}

\xsimsetup{
exercise/name={Question},
}


\begin{document}


\begin{exercise}
\begin{tasks}
\task Q 1 Task 1  (\addpoints{1}) % Tag Algebra
\task Q 1 Task 2 (\addpoints{2}) % Tag Data
\task Q 1 Task 3 (\addpoints{2}) % Tag Equations
\end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\begin{tasks}
\task Q 2 Task 1  (\addpoints{1}) % Tag Algebra
\task Q 2 Task 2 (\addpoints{2}) % Tag Data
\end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\begin{tasks}
\task Q 3 Task 1  (\addpoints{1}) % Tag Algebra
\task Q 3 Task 2 (\addpoints{1}) % Tag Data
\end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\begin{tasks}
\task Q 4 Task 1  (\addpoints{1}) % Tag Equations
\task Q 4 Task 2 (\addpoints{2}) % Tag Equations
\task Q 4 Task 3 (\addpoints{2}) % Tag Equations
\end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\vskip50mm

\gradingtable



\end{document}
```

The results of the above grade table is :

[image]

But I would like to modify the grading table to become:

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions: To tag and assign points, see my other code. // Create the table without `gradingtable`. // Use `expl3` to introduce global variables, which store information (current tag, points) and retrieve later when outputting the desired table. E.g. `expl3` also provides support to build needed sorting functions. // `xsim` needs to be extended a little in this respect. // `Parts` are not a concept in `xsim`, so you either need to introduce a new envirmoment and templates (for output) and data processing, or adapt your desired exam-concept to the `xsim exercise-solution` concept.

Comment: Dealing with `Parts` is discussed here as nested exercises: https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/67 // You could also contact the packages author directly, who ssems to be open to questions and suggestions, see here: https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim?lang=en .